# Android Studio - Can a function "know" which button press activated it?

Tags: android, function, android-studio, android-intent, android-button

Image I have 2 buttons, A and B. I have a function, called mystery(). Both buttons A and B, when pressed, will activate mystery(), but if button A is pressed, mystery() somehow knows it was button A that activated it, and if button B is pressed, mystery() somehow knows it was button B that activated it. If it was button A that activated mystery(), mystery() will stop the app, but if it was button B that activated mystery(), mystery will give the player 100 dollars.

That was just a random example, but basically what I'm asking is: is there a way to pass what button *triggered* a function? I get I could have two functions, mysteryA and mysteryB, where the former is linked to A and the latter is linked to B, and just copy and paste and have slight variations in each one, but there *must* be a more efficient way to do this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add a tag to a button or some known string/int and pass that into the function? mystery(whichButton : String)

Comment: You can check using _boolean_ flag

Comment: @Smashing another SA dev :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's possible (here's a java example)

```
public class abc extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
    }

    public void myMethod(View view) {
         //here, you can use something like view.getId() or anything else to identify which view called this method
      //you could do something like this :

     if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
         giveALocalNobody100Dollars();
     }else if (view.getId() == R.id.button3){
         giveItToHimEitherWayHeDeservesIt();
     }
    }
}
```

and your xml :

```
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="myMethod"/>
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="myMethod"/>
```

now, in your onClickListener, `myMethod` you have access to a `view`, and with this view you can determine which button called it

Comment: Hmm okay I sort of see what you're saying. So how do I access the view? Like (if view == something)? Or how can I use the view to determine which button called it I guess is what I'm asking.

Comment: in my update I included a comment, one of the ways is to use `view.getId` and with that you can simply check the ID of which view called it

Comment: Updated with a better example, glad to help @Evan :)

Answer (score 1):

- Can a function “know” which button press activated it?

  **Yes**
- is there a way to pass what button triggered a function?

  **Yes.** There are many ways to know whether the function was triggered by a particular button.

**Method 1:** You can pass a variable to the function with a mode say for example,

Button A triggers `mystery()` by passing a variable to it by `mystery("A");`

Button B triggers `mystery()` by passing a variable to it by `mystery("B")`;

Inside the function,

**Mystery:**

```
private void mystery(String mode) {
System.out.println(mode); // Here mode contains A or B
}
```

**Method 2:** Now again you can use a global variable with a boolean type.

`private boolean isButtonA;`

Now inside the click listener of Button A you can set `isButtonA = true;` and inside the click listener of Button B you can set `isButtonA = false;`

These are just the few easy ones. Feel free to suggest a few if I have missed something easier ;)